# waiting for animation to finish and check the result in Unit Test

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

I have a unit test in kotlin which performs a longClick and then checks if the width of a view has changed or not. The width should change during half second. But no matter how long I wait for it the received width is not as expected.

```
@Test
fun testLongClick() {
    var initialWidth = 0
    val listener = mock<TestInterface>(TestInterface::class.java)
    view?.let {


        it.findViewById<ImpulsesGroup>(R.id.test_default_impulse).getChildAt(2).setOnLongClickListener { child ->
            (child as ImpulsesButton).onLongClick(child, it.findViewById<ImpulsesGroup>(R.id.test_default_impulse), listener)
        }
        initialWidth = it.findViewById<ImpulsesGroup>(R.id.test_default_impulse).width
        assertThat("initial width", initialWidth, greaterThan(0))

        runOnUiThread {
            it.findViewById<ImpulsesGroup>(R.id.test_default_impulse).getChildAt(2).performLongClick()
        }

        await().atLeast(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        assertThat(view!!.findViewById<ImpulsesGroup>(R.id.test_default_impulse).width, Matchers.equalTo(3 * initialWidth))
    }
}
```

It seems that the final assetThat() is checked before the animation is done!

Comment: I think you need to create an async task ,then run your desired method

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement it though...I have been reading all about it but no success so far. Could you maybe provide a simple example  PLZ?

Comment: I am not home but asap I will answer with an example

Comment: Shouldn't you use Espresso for UI testing?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static class AsynchroniClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
          //what functions you need to do in the background
         //in your case get Current width of a view 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //now after you have the width call your function
        }
    }
```

Then don't forget to call the `AsynchroniClass` in your `onCreateView` like this:

```
new AsynchroniClass().execute();
```

Comment: did my answer help you?